# How to properly forward messages coming from client to Web Server in HTTPS? (Java Proxy Server)

Tags: java, http, proxy, forward

I have a working HTTP Proxy server. it can properly handle website using only HTTP and could also connect to HTTPS website. It can properly negotiate with the client's CONNECT request and start connecting to the destination server. now my problem is with some of HTTPS website that requires user login such as facebook and yahoo (though some site, I can do it successfully). it seems i could not properly forward messages coming from both side.(client and server)

what happen is everytime I try logging in to the said site. The browser behave it has successfully log in my account but instead of displaying the actual page, it returns to the login  page.

here is how my code work

// Daemon Class

```
while(true)
{
  ConnectionHandler handler = new ConnectionHandler(server.accept());
  handler.start();
}
```

// ConnectionHandler class

```
class ConnectionHandler extends Thread
{
    Socket client = null;
    Socket server = null;
    HTTPRequestHdr request = null;
    public ConnectionHandler(Socket socket)
    {
      client = socket;
      request = new HTTPRequestHdr();
    }

    public void run()
    {
       try
       {
         request.parse(client.getInputStream());
         server = new Socket(request.url,request.port);
         if(request.getMethod().equals("CONNECT");
         {
            // send 200 message to client then proceed
         }
         else
         {
            // send the request to server
         }

         Tunnel clientToServer = new Tunnel(client,server);
         Tunnel ServerToClient = new Tunnel(server,client);
         clientToServer.start();
         ServerToClient.start();

       }catch(Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

// Tunnel class

```
class Tunnel extends Thread
{
   Socket from = null;
   Socket to = null;
   public Tunnel(Socket from , Socket to)
   {
      this.from = from;
      this.to = to;
   }

   public void run()
   {
      OutputStream toClient = null;
      InputStream fromClient = null;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[50];
      int numberRead = 0;
      iny noResponse = 0;
      try
      {
       toClient = to.getOutputStream();
       fromClient = fro.getInputStream();

       int avail = fromClient.available();

        if(avail < 1)
        {
           Thread.sleep(20);
           noResponse += 20; 
        }
        else 
        {
           noResponse = 0; 
        }

        while(avail > 0)
        {
            numberRead = avail;
            numberRead = fromClient.read(buffer,0,numberRead);

            toClient.write(buffer,0,numberRead);
            toClient.flush();
            avail = fromClient.available();
        }

        if(noResponse > 30000)
        {
            // close connection
        }

      }catch(Exception e) {}

   }
}
```

I believe I fail to properly forward the data coming from both side. please tell me where
I am wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    int avail = fromClient.available();

    if(avail < 1)
    {
       Thread.sleep(20);
       noResponse += 20; 
    }
    else 
    {
       noResponse = 0; 
    }
    while(avail > 0)
    {
        numberRead = avail;
        numberRead = fromClient.read(buffer,0,numberRead);
        toClient.write(buffer,0,numberRead);
        toClient.flush();
        avail = fromClient.available();
    }
    if(noResponse > 30000)
    {
        // close connection
    }
} catch(Exception e) {}
```

This is all wrong. Sockets already have a timeout facility, and you are just wasting time calling `available()` and `sleep()`. All you need is this:

```
try
{
    fro.setSoTimeout(30000);
    while ((length = fromClient.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        toClient.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    // close sockets
    toClient.close();
    fromClient.close();
}
catch (SocketTimeoutException exc)
{
    // handle timeout, and certainly close the socket
}
catch (IOException exc)
{
    // exception handling
}
finally
{
    fro.close(); // close the input socket, NB not the output socket, the other thread will do that
}
```